# Why ResourceDictionary in same assembly is not found?

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have copied some functionality / files from one solution to another.

In solution 1 I have Windows Application DemoApp1 that has folders:

- Shell
- Ribbon/Resources

In Shell/ShellView.xaml

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/Ribbon/Resources/Ribbon.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

above works with no problem.

In solution 2 I have Windows Application DemoApp2 that does very little. App-class inherits from a class in C# Class Library DemoApp2Feature that does most of the things.

The Shell and Ribbond folder structure and files are the same in Class Library DemoApp2Feature. However here that above results in:

XamlParseException 'Set property 'System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.Source' threw an excetion'.

When I look in VS2015 exception details BaseUri looks like this:

{pack://application:,,,/DemoApp2Feature;component/shell/shellview.xaml}

I would like to keep the files and folder-structure the same also in DemoApp2Feature because there's dozens of files that has these MergedDictionaries-definitions. So how can I tell what is the base for the place where to look for ResourceDictionaries for DemoApp2Feature.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand your scenario, but this page explains the proper format for pack URIs depending upon where the resource is:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx

[image]

Comment: thanks! I am trying to ask why Relative Pack URI when Resource file in local (I assume this means same) assembly does not work runtime while it IMO should "/SubFolder/ResourceFile.xaml". In other solution they work.